# ¿Cómo integrar extjs con un proyecto laravel?

Tags: laravel, extjs

Estoy trabajando con `laravel` y quería implementar de la manera más adecuada `extjs` al proyecto pero no encuentro nada concreto en internet hasta el momento.

La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente:

```
app
bootstrap
config
database
public 
----ext
--------app
------------model
------------store
------------view
------------Application.js      <---- Archivo que carga patrón MVC
--------build
--------classic
--------ext
--------modern
--------resources
--------app.js                  <---- Archivo principal de extjs
--------Todos los otros archivos de extjs
Todas las otras carpetas y archivos de laravel
```

En el archivo `blade` donde cargo los `scripts` llamo a `extjs` y mis demás librerías de la siguiente forma

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('ext/ext/build/ext-all.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('ext/ext/build/ext-all-debug.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('ext/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Pero me genera un error `404` al llamar el archivo `Application.js` úbicado en el directorio `public\ext\app\Application.js` cómo se muestra arriba en la estructura del proyecto, por lo tanto no renderiza nada ni muestra nada.

Mi pregunta en sí sería ¿cómo debo integrar `extjs` a un proyecto `laravel` para trabajar correctamente con cada patrón desde el cliente y desde el servidor?

Comment: Utiliza el gestor de dependencias **npm** y revisa Laravel mix: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix o añadelo simplemte como cualquier otro asset mas. Igualmente esa libreria me parace excesivamente pesada y lenta.

Comment: @Xerif La verdad concuerdo con lo último, gracias por el comentario, le echaré un vistazo, de todas maneras me toca ya que es por cuestiones del trabajo que ando aprendiendo esta tecnología :) saludos